# center a map according to polyline icon offset

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to play animation by changing icon offset of polyline using a timer

```
var count =0
var timer = setInterval(function(){
   if(count > 199) clearInterval(timer);
   var icons = poly.get('icons');
   icons[0].offSet = (count/2) + '%';
   poly.set('icons') =icons; 
   count ++;
});
```

the problem is that i need to center the map according to the current icon offset by i failed since my points are not equidistant , so is there any way to get icon position and center the map ?

thank's for help !

Answer (score 0):

I found a little workaround that may help !

there is a google map extension that computes the total distance of a polyline then with that we can have the point at a given distance according to the offset !

```
var distance = poly.Distance();
```

for offset 0.1 we'll look for point at :

```
var point = poly.GetPointAtDistance(0.1 * distance);
```

or 
    var point = poly.GetIndexAtDistance(0.1 * distance);

hope it helps !

[link to the extension](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js)